# Ubuntu Software Center: Add option to launch application after installation

Tags: launcher, software-center

Does any body know why Ubuntu Software Center can not launch applications after installation ?

All user install application only for one purpose - launch it and use.
Why we need to install it and after that search it in number of menus.

Even Packages are mixed with applications that why not just allow to launch only applications that put smth in menu.

Example of such convenient application center - android market, ... .
Ubuntu 11.10 have pretty/sexy center but .... vital function still missed.

Comment: you should file a bug on launchpad requesting the feature.

Comment: I tried Fedora's their "Add/Remove Software" do Run after installation.
I will wait a bit for answer and then open issue against Ubutnu Software Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/23045/) at brainstorm and have an answer, this is long discussion at launch pad, [read here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/420517)